# Oracle Installation for client server connection in lab

Tags: database, oracle

i don't know anything about oracle. Our faculty members assign us for setup lab(class lab) in client server connection. can anyone please say what the process and what component i should install and how to configure it.
Lab PC has linux based OS.
N.B. i didn't find any easy guide by googling it.

Answer (score 1):

For the DB, download Oracle Database XE edition from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/xe-downloads.html  The installation guide is https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinl/installation-guide.html.  You can google for various blog posts etc that will help.

If the "client" computer is on a different machine, then install Oracle Instant Client from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html.  The instructions are at the bottom of the page.

If you only have one computer then don't install Instant Client.  The Oracle Database libraries can also be used by applications to connect to the database.

Comment: After connecting DB with client, DB work as server? or, does it need extra configuration to be work as server? and then how do connect server with instant client?

Comment: The "client" is really a set of libraries and a few tools (e..g SQL*Plus).  These are available in the DB install directories, so if you use them (from the DB installation), the DB will continue working fine.  How you use the tools and libraries (whether they are in the DB installation, or in Instant Client) will depend on your application.  E.g. You could using Python, ODBC, JDBC, or others, or run custom applications written in C or C++ (and more).  Update your question with more detail.

Comment: In our lab, all the PC connected through LAN network. and there is no Oracle database or client software. so, our task is make a database in one PC and and other computer will work as client then.

Comment: If you have two computers, then install Oracle DB on one, and Oracle Instant Client on the other.   Look at the architecture diagram in https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/introduction.html to understand.  I still don't know what tools or applications you want to run on the "client" computer, so I can't say more.

Answer (score 1):

you can check my article from here; step by step installation

http://www.cansayin.com/2019/11/16/oracle12c-installation/

You have to install packages for oracle and set some parameter on your operating system before installation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, there's the database server in your lab which has an Oracle database. Your assignment is to establish connection to it from your PC.

If that's so, you'll need to install Oracle Client software. It can be downloaded from the [Oracle Technology Network](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/) < a href="https://www.oracle.com/downloads/#category-database">Download section.

The simplest option is to download & install the [Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html). Navigate to your operating system version, download it and run the setup.

If you visit [this page](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html), you'll find installation instructions at the bottom of the page.

I don't use Linux so I can't guide you based on my own experience, sorry.

Once you're done, you'll have to edit the TNSNAMES.ORA file in order to include database's alias (DBA should tell you that information if you don't know it). Basically, that should be enough to establish the connection.